# jQuery - submit button by clicking containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My form submits by clicking one of two buttons.

```
<form method="post" action="http://testing.com">
  <div class="container red">
    <button type="submit" name="some_name" value="some_value">Btn</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container blue">
    <button type="submit" name="some_other_name" value="some_other_value">Btn</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If the user clicks the containing `div`, I want it to submit the button. I have tried the following:

```
$("div.container").click(function(){
  $(this).find("button").click();
});
```

And I have also tried `.submit()` but neither seem to work. I know there are alternative methods such as using hidden inputs and submitting the form itself, but I'm curious how to specifically submit via a button.

As you can see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/2/), clicking the button works. Clicking the `div` does nothing.

Comment: $(someElement).click(); does not trigger a native mouse click event like you'd expect, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging your output and you'll find your problem:

```
$(".container").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicking");
    $("button", this).click();
});
```

Produces 1000 log events and then dies due to too much recursion. Clearly the child `.click()` is firing the event which then propagates to the parent and the initial handler is run again.

The other proposed solutions to simply submit the form are incorrect, as that *will not* post the key-value pair associated with the button you would want to click. The best approach I can think of is to use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) such that the event on the parent is immediately destroyed. That way you'll retain posting the value of the unique button, but you'll avoid the recursion, [(see Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/6/):

```
$(".container").one("click", function() {
    $("button", this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(this).parent().submit();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/3/)

**Update:**

To avoid infinite recursion use [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/event.stopPropagation)

```
$("div.container").click(function(){
         $(this).children('button').click();
});

$("button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/10/)

Comment: I want to submit via the button, not just submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Updated with native click: http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/7/

Oooh, what a tricky one. It's a problem with using:

```
$(someElement).click();
```

This does not actually simulate a native click event, like the submit button needs.
It make a jquery click, it's a pretty nuanced problem.
To simulate a real mouse click exactly as a user makes: 
(warning, ugly low level code)

```
$("div.container").click(function(){
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
    $(this).find("button")[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with a solution, albeit a lot trickier than the answer I have accepted!

Comment: Yep, I like his too, it's simpler for your question. You can also use mine on anchors and anything else to simulate real clicks, by the way - fun to make testing functions with it, or freak people out by running a bunch on your page without when you demo

Answer (score -1):

Try to set that form a name, like "myForm"

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://testing.com">
    <div class="container red">
        <button type="submit" name="some_name" value="some_value">Btn</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container blue">
        <button type="submit" name="some_name" value="some_value">Btn</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then change a litle bit your javascript, using the form `submit()` method

```
$("div.container").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SLkX2/4/

Comment: I want to submit via the button, not just submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$("div.container").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/SLkX2/5/